# How to concatenate string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario in which I have a table `Company` with some columns on which I want to query

1. Name
2. IsHighPriority
3. Coupons ( Foreign Key )

Now if `High Priority` is true I want to put `(High Priorty)` in front of company name column and if there a more then 3 coupons in a company then I want to put `(Important)` in front of company name

How to do this? Please help me and thanks in advance

**Edit**

What should I do if I want to add this all in a SQL view, because when I tried to add this in SQL view its giving error

> Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 1.

**Edit#2**

I want to select company coupon count base on this query

```
RejectProcessed = 0 and ReviewVerify = 0 and isPublish = 0 and ForSupervisor = 0
```

I mean when we are getting count of coupon on every company then we should insert this query on every coupon these are the field which are already exists in COUPON table  .

Please let me know if you need more details

This is how i created nt view

```
  Create view GetCompanyNames as
   SELECT  CASE WHEN COALESCE(b.totalCoupons, 0) > 3 THEN a.Name +'(Important) '
         WHEN IsHighPriority = 1 THEN a.Name +'(High Priority) '
        ELSE a.Name +''
    END  AS CompanyName
  FROM    Company a
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT  Name, COUNT(*) totalCoupons
        FROM    Company
        GROUP   BY Name
    ) b ON a.name = b.name
```

Comment: please add some SQL query and table schema

Comment: Show us how you tried to create the view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COALESCE(b.totalCoupons, 0) > 3 THEN '(Important) '
            WHEN IsHighPriority = 1 THEN '(High Priority) '
            ELSE ''
        END + a.Name AS CompanyName
FROM    Company a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Name, COUNT(*) totalCoupons
            FROM    Company
            GROUP   BY Name
        ) b ON a.name = b.name
```

Comment: did you try to wrap it in a view?

Comment: yes i simply add this statement at the top of query `Create view GetCompanyNames as`

Comment: its ok ,@JW  . But can you help me if i have another thing in this context ?

Comment: its quite difficult please ask what we want to know ?

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631945/get-count-in-one-to-many-relation-in-sql

Answer (score -2):

You can concatenate strings with `+` operator

```
select 'a'+'b'
```

selects text 'ab'